# updating user profile fields django

Tags: python, django

Should be a simple answer but I can't figure out what's wrong here...

I have a user profile with a couple of simple fields.  I'm trying to update them like so:

```
if data['dob'] != None:     
    request.user.profile.dob = data['dob']  

request.user.profile.save()
```

This doesn't seem to have any effect at all though.

p.s. i am using a nice little trick in my UserProfile class that looks like this:

```
User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

Could this be part of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what happens in your code.

If there's a `dob` in your data, you call `request.user.profile`. This calls your property, which makes a request to the database and gets or creates a Profile instance.

Next, you call `request.user.profile` again. Guess what this does? Makes a fresh call to the database, and gets an instance of the Profile again. But of course this is a new instance, even though it's referring to the same database row, so it won't have the value for `dob` you just set on the last version.

Now, potentially you could solve this by storing the profile in a local variable:

```
profile = request.user.profile
profile.dob = data['dob']
profile.save()
```

But to be honest, I'd drop the whole hacking around with the profile property. It's going to  cause you all sorts of problems.

Comment: thanks for your clear answer.  What other problems could you foresee with this method?  Also, even if I was using `request.user.get_profile()` as normal, the problem would still be present in my implementation?

Comment: get_profile is specifically written to avoid that, as it caches the profile instance on first lookup. See the code in django.contrib.auth.models.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use the suggested method of tying a profile to a django user:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

In the meantime, remove the [0] at the end of the UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u) as that method only returns a single object regardless